# XSLT: character (en-dash ) encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, xslt-1.0

I am stuck into very srerious problem , please help me.

I have input file which have some characters (en-dash) , **SWITCH – Ethernet Access** is the field having en- dash character in the Following input  data.

```xml
<CsvData><![CDATA[Type=Upload Centers

, Corporation,69,SWITCH - Dune,R&D,DNX
,Corporation,70,SWITCH – Ethernet Access,R&D,EA
,Canada Ltd.,70,SWITCH – Ethernet Access,R&D,EA
, Networking Technology (Shanghai) Co. Ltd.,70,SWITCH – Ethernet Access,R&D,EA
, Japan G.K.,70,SWITCH – Ethernet Access,R&D,EA
, Corporation,55,Network - Switch,R&D,XGS
]]></CsvData>
```

When i use my XSLT to transform , i get the following error .

```
ERROR: XSLT Service failed. Failed to transform document Exception: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Following is the XSLT code :

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" cdata-section-     elements="CsvData"/>
    <xsl:param name="UserName"/>
    <xsl:param name="Password"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        SOAPAction: "urn:upload"
        Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas/" xmlns:web="http:/site">
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:text>
                </xsl:text>
                <web:upload>
                    <xsl:text>
                    </xsl:text>     
                    <web:username><xsl:value-of select="$UserName"/>      </web:username>
                    <xsl:text>
                    </xsl:text>
                    <web:password><xsl:value-of select="$Password"/>     </web:password>
                    <xsl:text>
                    </xsl:text>

                    <web:data>
                    <!-- CDATA section in output file generated -->
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ <![CDATA[  ]]>     </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CsvData" />
                    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[>]]>    </xsl:text>
                </web:data>
            </web:upload></soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please find something why this XSLT code is failing when en-dash is supported in UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

The probable reason is that the input file is not in fact UTF-8 encoded. If it is actually windows-1252 (Windows Latin 1) encoded, then EN DASH appears in it as octet 96 (hexadecimal); when the data is being interpreted as UTF-8, it causes an error condition just like the one that was reported.

To check this out, open the input file e.g. in Notepad++ and set the encoding to ANSI. If it looks OK (there is EN DASH where you expect it to be), then my analysis was correct, and you need to convert the file to UTF-8 with a command in Notepad++, then save it.

There are many ways to change the encoding of a file, I just mentioned a simple one. If the file is dynamically generated, you need to modify the generation process – or maybe declare the file as windows-1252 encoded, though this is generally not a good idea (restricts the character repertoire that can be used).

Comment: i have copied data in notepad ++ and then i encode the data in UTF-8 , x96 is placed in the place of en dash.

and if i convert this file into UTF-8 format , then my XSLT works fine .

So does it means that i have to convert my file to UTF-8 encoding.

But the problem is file is auto generated i cannot change its encoding . 

Is there any other way i can handle this .

Thanks for ur help

Comment: If you can affect the very start of the data file, you could add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>` there, to declare windows-1252 encoding. Other than that, I guess you would need to affect the program used to open the data file, telling it to use windows-1252 encoding. It that file is accessed via HTTP, you could use the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Yes u are right , adding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?> in the start , resolve my issue , now i see if my code allows me to add this ..
Thank u very much for ur great help.

Comment: I had a similar problem with opposite symptoms (dash was NOT displayed correctly when switching to ANSI), the solution was to add "<xsl:output byte-order-mark="yes" />" so that the transform will add the correct BOM for other programs to read. It's not a solution for OP's problem, but it might help someone else who finds this answer, but needs this info.